# No funciona Javascript en asp.net core mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

Estoy tratando de realizar algunas validaciones mediante javascript en una solución de asp.net core pero por algún motivo pareciera que el código javascript no funciona. Soy nuevo trabajando en asp.net core y no estoy seguro de estar realizando el procedimiento correcto.

```js
function prueba() {

    var id = document.getElementById("identidad");

    if (id > 2) {
        alert(" La identidad no puede ser mayor a 2 ")
    }




}
```

```html
@model VivoSegura.Models.Clientes

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<script src ="~/js/site.js" type = "text/javascript">  </script>


<h4>Nuevo Cliente</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form  asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Nombre" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Nombre" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Nombre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Apellido" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Apellido" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Apellido" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Identidad" class="control-label"></label>
                <input id="identidad" asp-for="Identidad" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Identidad" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FechaInicial" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FechaInicial" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FechaInicial" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input asp-for="Citologia" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Citologia)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input asp-for="Papanicolau" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Papanicolau)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input asp-for="ExamenOrina" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ExamenOrina)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Mamografia" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="radio" asp-for="Mamografia" class="form-control" value="Si" />Si
                <input type="radio" asp-for="Mamografia" class="form-control" value="No" />No
                <span asp-validation-for="Mamografia" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FechaPrimeraCita" class="control-label"></label>
                <input  asp-for="FechaPrimeraCita" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FechaPrimeraCita" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FechaSegundaCita" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FechaSegundaCita" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FechaSegundaCita" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-default" onsubmit="prueba()" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la función de JavaScript, `getElementById` devuelve un objeto de HTML (DOM), no el valor del `<input>`.  Prueba con `id.value`

```
var id = document.getElementById("identidad");

if (id.value > 2) { ....
```

Comment: al ingresar "id."  solo me indica valueof y nodevalue como lo indique al momento de querer guardar el valor en la variable id. Pero no se si es la sintaxis correcta ya que no había visto ninguno de las 2 opciones antes. En php era simplemente indicar .value como lo mencionas pero aquí no me lo permite.

Comment: Adivino que estás trabajando con Visual Studio, el autocompletado de JavaScript no es muy confiable. Escribe `.value` y ejecútalo no más.

Comment: function prueba() {

    var id = document.getElementById("identidad").value;

    if (id.value > 2) {
        alert(" La identidad no puede ser mayor a 2 ")
    }

Lo intenté de esa manera y nada amigo, según la lógica me parece debería de funcionar. No logró entender cual es el problema.

Comment: por que llamar id.value cuando ya ese valor esta almacenado en id. deberia ser if(id > 2){....}